# Which design pattern to apply

Tags: java, design-patterns

Lets say we have to retrive data of class: Trade. This trade class has many parameters like A, B, C....

```
class A { retrieveTradeDataWithA(); and many more methods which do something }

class B { retrieveTradeDataWithB(); and many more methods which do something }

class LetsSaySomeResource {

  @Inject
  private A classAInstance;
  @Inject
  private B classBInstance;

  public void getTradeDataBasedOnA(){   
    classAInstance.retrieveTradeDataWithA();
  }
  public void getTradeDataBasedOnB(){   
    classBInstance.retrieveTradeDataWithB();
  }
}
```

Now the requirement is we want to fetch some trade data based on A and B both and later on maybe more classes like A and B will be added to get data based on this. How shall i make the design more flexible?

Like,

```
public void getDataBasedOnAandB(){
}
```

Or, later on C class can come, so i dont want to keep injecting filters like A,B....
Can someone help on this?

Comment: hi i have edited my requirement to be little more clear, hope this can help to give me some idea

Comment: I suspect something like this could help you - http://coders-kitchen.com/2013/01/24/jee-and-dynamic-dependency-injection/

Answer (score 4):

First create an interface that will define the contract for doing something :

```
public interface IData {
    void doSomething();
}
```

Then create the concrete implementations to do something :

```
public class DataA implements IData {

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // TODO Do something for A

    }

}

public class DataB implements IData {

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // TODO Do something for B
    }

}
```

And finally a class that will actually do something :

```
public class DataDAO {
    private List<IData> dataList;

    public DataDAO(List<IData> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        for(IData data : dataList) {
            data.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's take your use cases :

do something for A :

```
 List<IData> dataAList = new ArrayList<IData>();
 dataList.add(new DataA());
 DataDAO dataADAO = new DataDAO(dataAList);
 dataADAO.doSomething();
```

do something for A and B :

```
 List<IData> dataAList = new ArrayList<IData>();
 dataList.add(new DataA());
 dataList.add(new DataB());
 DataDAO dataADAO = new DataDAO(dataAList);
 dataADAO.doSomething();
```

Comment: Hi, i think this cannot solve the issue for AandB parameters if i want to filter with together.  i have edited my requirement to be little more clear, hope this can help to give me some idea.

Comment: With the above solution, you don't need to keep injecting filters. You just need to create a list of concrete IData implementation as I have already shown in the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It may look something like this:

```
class LetsSaySomeResource {
    @Resource
    private Map<String, DataAccessInterface> instanceToDataAccessMapping;

    public DateAggregationResult getDataFor(String... instanceNames) {
        DataAggregationResult result = new DataAggregationResult(); // some list or whatever
        for (String instanceName : instanceNames) {
            Data data = instanceToDataAccessMapping.get(instanceName).getData();
            /**
             * Add this data to aggregation result here
             */
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: what about doSomthingForAandB? Your answer can only cover doSomethingForA or doSomthingForB but not both. See my answer instead.

Comment: You can allow passing several instanceNames to Resource method and aggregate the result before returning actual Data. I don't see any problem here.

Comment: Yes but getDataFor is one dimensional. What I mean by this is it can operate on only on instanceName at a time so doesn't matter how many entries are ther in the map. The caller will have to call this getDataFor method multiple times which kind of makes the map pointless. Now if you were to iterate over the map in getDataFor method, it would make sense. But again, why use a map when you can use a list?

Comment: I still don't agree with using a map as it serves no purpose. You not only need to maintain strings representing method calls but you also need to iterate and call get on the map each time. A simple list of DataAccessInterface passed to this method would suffice. See my answer.

Comment: Map will guarantee you constant access speed to any number of undelying DataSource objects. Lists will not scale up in a same way. Also, strings may be substituted with enumeration. Is that good enough?

Comment: String, enumeration, integers, etc doesn't matter. You don't need those extra placeholders. Also, in this particular case, the map will take up more space. Think of it. You will have to define constants for all method names that will be used as keys : doSomethingForA, doSomethingForB.....doSomethingForZ. Imagine what happens when you have 100 methods? It's not only a maintenance nightmare but an unnecessary overhead. Even if there were only 4 or 5 methods, it's still an unnecessary overhead to have placeholders for the keys.

Comment: Not to forget the list of instance names that you will pass to the getDataFor method. Don't forget that we are simply traversing the List and not searching the list. If we use a map, we will do as many get's as the number of methods. Therefore, no difference between a map and a list IMO.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, but it doesn't give information for A&B if combined

Comment: hi i have edited my requirement to be little more clear, hope this can help to give me some idea

Comment: Besides the discussion about the storage structure, @bhupen just pass by multiple instance identifiers and add some aggregation logic after the data retrieval. What you can do, to add some flexibility (if necessary) pass also an Aggregator as parameter into the method, which will take care of the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). If your classes will grow over time always based on previous requirements, you could add the additional computations by decorating them.

Your example is still very abstract so it is hard to tell whether your additional classes are interdependent or simply "extended" (a simple inheritance would do).

Or completely decoupled so something like SimY4 did could help (use e.g. a variation of the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)).

Comment: Using a list eliminates the need to use the decorator pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think template design pattern would be useful here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

you can define your template method in the base class and let the sub classes implementing this class define their own algorithm to do this. Do read the wiki link and you would find your way out.